# Can I fix the MBR using a 1 year old MBR Backup?

Tags: windows-7, mbr

I've got a secondary HDD that failed. It looks like it was the MBR. Unfortunately the backup service I was using doesn't backup Virtual Disks (despite saying they "backup all files" so I lost some important Vms.

I do have an older backup of that HDD. It doesn't have the Vms but it has the MBR (Master Book Record). I'm not sure how often that MBR changes and, thus, whether the old MBR would work.

SYMPTOMS

The old HDD is not even come up on a new PC (connected via adapter to USB). Windows reports that it needs to be formatted.

Comment: No matter what you do - image the disk first. Also, try it in a linux box, sometimes linux will read disks windows can't, which is a ridiculously quick fix, cause then you can just pull the files off.

Answer (score 1):

> **Can I fix the MBR using a 1 year old MBR Backup?**

If you have an image of the MBR of this machine and a way to push the image to it then I'm sure you could push it back to it but I normally just rebuilt the MBR or delete it and then rebuild it.

I typically ensure I have a full disk image already or at least all my data backed up from the drive which I need to push images to so you should backup your data beforehand as well.

---

Otherwise, if you're able to do a MBR delete and then rebuild, hop on over to the [Fix the MBR – Guide for Windows XP, Vista, 7, 8, 8.1, 10](https://neosmart.net/wiki/fix-mbr/) and follow the instruction for your OS accordingly.

> ### [Fix the MBR in Windows 7](https://neosmart.net/wiki/fix-mbr/)
>
> *You need your original Windows 7 installation DVD to boot into System Recovery Options and run Command Prompt.*
>
> > *If you don’t have the Windows 7 installation CD/DVD to run Command Prompt, go to [Fix MBR with Easy Recovery
> >     Essentials.](https://neosmart.net/wiki/fix-mbr/#Fix_the_MBR_with_Easy_Recovery_Essentials)*
>
> The instructions are:
>
> 1. Boot from the Windows 7 installation DVD
> 2. At the “Press any key to boot from CD or DVD…”, press any key to boot from the DVD
> 3. Select a language
> 4. Select a keyboard layout
> 5. Click Next
> 6. Select the operating system and click Next. The “Use recovery tools that can help fix problems starting Windows” must be checked when you
>      select the operating system.
> 7. At the System Recovery Options screen, click on Command Prompt
> 8. When Command Prompt successfully loads, type this command:
>
>    - `bootrec /rebuildbcd`
> 9. Press Enter
> 10. Type the next command:
>
>     - `bootrec /fixmbr`
> 11. Press <kbd>`Enter`</kbd>
> 12. Type the next command:
>
>     - `bootrec /fixboot`
> 13. Press <kbd>`Enter`</kbd>
> 14. Remove the installation DVD from the disk tray and restart your computer
>
> If `bootrec /fixmbr` and `bootrec /fixboot` doesn’t work, try
>   restoring the boot sector code of your Windows 7:
>
> 1. Determine the drive letter of your Windows installation CD/DVD by typing these commands in the Command Prompt:
>
>    - `diskpart`
>    - `select disk 0`
>    - `list volume`
> 2. Look for the “CD-ROM” word in a “Type” column. This item is your CD/DVD installation drive letter. If the drive letter is D:\, type
>      these commands:
>
>    - `exit`
>    - `D:`
>    - `cd boot`
>    - `dir`
>
> If the drive letter is different than D:\, replace the second command
>   with the drive letter you have noted from the previous list volume
>   command.
>
> 3. Type this command:
>
>    - `bootsect /nt60 SYS /mbr`
> 4. Press <kbd>`Enter`</kbd>
> 5. Remove the CD/DVD from the disk tray
> 6. Type `Exit`
> 7. Press <kbd>`Enter`</kbd> to restart your computer
>
> <sub>[source](https://neosmart.net/wiki/fix-mbr/)</sub>