# How can I fix the Windows Update error message, "We couldn't update the system reserved partition?"

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, windows-update

I am unable to update Windows. When Windows Update tries to run, I get an error message that has a "Fix issues" button.

[image: Windows update error message with "Fix issues" button]

Pressing that brings up a process that eventually gives the error message, "We couldn't update the system reserved partition."

[image: "We couldn't update the system reserved partition."]

It turns out I didn't have a System Reserved partition. I figured it might work to create it, so I did, using [Option 1](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/119151-system-reserved-create-using-disk-management.html) from this link. Now my partitions look like this, but I still get the same error as above.

[image]

Most of the information surrounding this error refers to increasing the available space on the System Reserved partition, but as the screenshot shows, there's plenty of space on the partition.

How can I debug this update error?

Comment: Have you *tried* enlarging it?  I ran into the same issue when I did the free upgrade from Windows 7 to Windows 10.  After I increased the size of the system partition, the upgrade completed successfully.

Comment: @CharlesBurge I mean, in some sense yes, in that it wasn't there, and now it is. So it went from zero space to 188MB free.

Comment: Kris - Have a look here on the [MS KB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3086249/we-couldn-t-update-system-reserved-partition-error-installing-windows), there is the answer in here based on which option of either [GPT or MBR](https://www.howtogeek.com/245610/how-to-check-if-a-disk-uses-gpt-or-mbr-and-how-to-convert-between-the-two/)

Comment: Your System Reserved partition is not large enough - it's only 200 MB, but Windows 10 needs 500 MB.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT That link says to `cd Boot\Fonts` but that directory does not exist on my System Reserved partition.

Comment: @KrisHarper See if perhaps rebuilding the MBR will help: https://superuser.com/questions/1188726/can-i-fix-the-mbr-using-a-1-year-old-mbr-backup/1188761#1188761 but you should ensure you have system backups beforehand just in case.The MBR is supposed to be at the very beginning of the disk when you create the first partition. Perhaps simply rebuilding it will put it where it needs to be and will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is correct : Your System Reserved partition is not large enough.

Your partition has 200 MB, but for Windows 10 the recommended size is 500 MB.

If this does not work, I think that the System Reserved partition you created
manually is not used because of the way in which the disk was partitioned
and Windows installed.

The simplest solution would be to delete the System Reserved partition,
then do [Startup Repair](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27649-run-startup-repair-windows-10-a.html).
If that doesn't help, then I can only think of
[Repair Install Windows](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Comment: Cool. I will try resizing it when I get home tonight.

Comment: I resized it so now [it's 1GB](https://i.imgur.com/uB9uvCF.png), but I still get the same error message, "We couldn't update the system reserved partition."

Comment: I think your System Reserved partition is badly created. Can you take a screenshot of Disk Management with the Status column fully displayed? Is your Windows 64-bit? Do you have BIOS+MBR or do you have UEFI+GPT?

Comment: [Here's a screenshot of the full Status column.](https://i.imgur.com/p3i8iYi.png) My disk [is MBR](https://i.imgur.com/v7DGfrq.png), although I boot using UEFI since this is not my primary boot device.

Comment: I think the explanation is that you don't have (or need) a real System Reserved partition. Try to reduce the one you created to 500 MB and push it so you have unallocated space below the EFI partition. Add this space to the EFI partition using a good third-party product, for example with Easus - see [link](https://www.easeus.com/partition-manager-software/resize-efi-partition.html). Be careful, since destroying the EFI partition means no boot.

Comment: This doesn't make sense because there is no EFI partition on this disk.

Comment: Disk 1 partition 3 ?

Comment: Right, it's on a separate disk. The System Reserved partition is on Disk 0. So resizing that partition to add space to the EFI partition makes no sense.

Comment: You boot using EFI so you do use it. Resizing the EFI is one solution I can offer. Another solution would be to make more free space on the C partition, and the explanation is that if when you installed Windows there was no unallocated disk space for the System Reserved partition, the installer would install Windows onto a single partition, meaning C, which now also serves as the System Reserved partition.

Comment: I didn't say I didn't use the EFI partition, I said that it's on a different disk, so reducing the size of the System Reserved partition and adding that space to the EFI partition is impossible—they are on *different disks*. The C: partition has over 40GB of free space. Surely that's enough?

Comment: 40 GB is not enough for a System Reserved partition. I think you boot with the EFI, then continue to boot Windows from the other disk, so both are a possible problem area.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Disk 1 is my boot device, and Disk 0 boots from the bootloader. I am confused about how 40GB is not large enough for a System Reserved partition. In your answer you said it needs to be 500MB. Now it's 40GB isn't enough?

Comment: Sorry, I answered too quickly. Yes, there are only two options, so it seems that the EFI partition is to blame. The System Reserved partition you created seems to me to be ignored. If enlarging the EFI partition does not work, you might need stronger measures, but we'll wait and see.

Comment: Same issue now that my EFI partition (on a *separate disk*) [is 500MB](https://i.imgur.com/kqclcH3.png).

Comment: I'm handicapped by not knowing the history of your disk. I think you will need to delete the System Reserved partition, then do [Startup Repair](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27649-run-startup-repair-windows-10-a.html). If that doesn't help, then I can only think of [Repair Install Windows](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Comment: Okay, got it. The EFI partition was sized up, but the filesystem didn't expand. After adding a larger filesystem the updates installed normally. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

On my 10 PC (which was updated from 7), the system reserved is the first partition on disk 0 (may not matter) and has attributes in Disk Management of Active (like yours) but also System and Primary. This may be vital.

Setting the partition as active is done by right clicking it in Disk Management and choosing the option. Putting the boot information on the reserved partition and marking it system (Microsoft switched the terms for some reason) is more involved. It is late here, but I will return if that is needed for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

hello my system partition is 100 mb and I try this link to mount the partition and delete fonts, it work!!!!
https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/we-couldnt-update-system-reserved-partition-error-windows-10/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).